# Audio is distorted after playing game, "System interrupts" at 15% of CPU Usage

Tags: windows-8, audio, process, cpu-usage

It doesn't happen before. Just yesterday, I played a game and I quit it. I was bored and listened to some music and then the audio is so bad that the quality had distortion. Not just the song, but all of the sounds. The audio was like something you tune the volume on a speaker and the speaker just has the kind of distorted sound.

I also noticed the "System interrupts" process stays at 10% to 15%. It is just weird because it's 'normal' for my laptop since that process always stays at the percentage after I play my game without the sound being distorted, but yesterday and today was different.

The process isn't even possible to end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Um okay, I solved it...

I am using a Realtek sound card, so my laptop came pre-installed with a software called "Realtek HD Audio Manager" which you can tweak audio frequencies and sound quality.

I went in to disable all sound effects and changed the default format to "24 Bits, 192000 Hz (Studio Quality)" and the audio distortion is gone.